# Is there priority for box shadow of different browsers? (CSS)

Tags: css, webkit, vendor-prefix, box-shadow

I just met a problem of box shadow.

**1. Is there any priority of `box-shadow`?**

for example:

```
box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px #292929;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px #292929;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px #292929;
```

and

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px #292929;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px #292929;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px #292929;
```

I saw many setting like the second one, why it's always "moz->webkit->basic setting"?

**2. Why we need `-moz-box-shadow` and `-webkit-box-shadow` even if we have box-shadow?**

Comment: -moz-box-shadow and -webkit-box-shadow are there for older browsers. Browsers will just ignore them if they use box-shadow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your second question first; how far back you want your browser support to go will determine whether or not you need to prefix a property and which prefixes to use. (You can check the browser compatibility table for `box-shadow` on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow).)

With regard to the order; the order of the prefixed properties is irrelevant (personally, I prefer alphabetical order) as a browser will simply ignore any property it doesn't understand.

The only important thing with the order is that the **un**prefixed property *must* be last as, if it were to be followed by a prefixed version that the browser understands, that prefixed version would override the unprefixed version, which could lead to problems if the prefixed version uses non-standard syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll use it in alphabetical order and the general one in the last.

Comment: Hello again. Is there any other tags needed to be used as this setting?

Answer (score 1):

That is based on the browser,`-moz-box-shadow` used especially for mozilla,like wise `-webkitbox-shadow` for chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this: **[Reference](https://css-tricks.com/ordering-css3-properties/)**

```
-webkit-box-shadow:10px 10px 5px #000;
-moz-box-shadow:10px 10px 5px #000;
box-shadow:10px 10px 5px #000;
```

When writing CSS3 properties, the modern wisdom is to list the "real" property last and the vendor prefixes first.. So its not advisable to use in this way

```
box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px #292929;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px #292929;
-webkitbox-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px #292929;
```

Firefox 3.6- needs `-moz-`. From 4 up, unprefixed is fine.

Chrome, iOS 3.x, Safari 4- needs `-webkit-`

Answer (score 0):

To support some css3 in all browsers we need to add prefix

-moz- : Mozila Firefox,
-webkit- :Chrome, safari
-ms- : IE
-o-: opera,

By using this we can apply different css property to different browsers.